# OnPaint is updated too often

Tags: c++, mfc, cpu, freeze, onpaint

I have a problem with the OnPaint method of CFrameWnd, and I cant seem to figure out what is happening. OnPaint is called approx every 10 ms, which causes the computer to freeze. Checked CPU usage and this app takes up 50%!

The application is a very simple MFC app, which is written in one file.

```
// Includes are done here...

class MFC_Tutorial_Window : public CFrameWnd
{
std::string data;

public:
    MFC_Tutorial_Window()
    {
         this->data = "";
         Create(NULL, "Data Win");  // Create window
    }

    void OnPaint()
    {   
        CDC* pDC = GetDC();

        CString s = CString(this->data.c_str());
        RECT rc;

        HWND hwnd = this->m_hWnd;
        if(hwnd != NULL) {
            ::GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);

            rc.top = rc.bottom/2;

            if(pDC != NULL && pDC->m_hDC != NULL) {
                pDC->DrawText(s, &rc, DT_CENTER);
            }
        }
    }

    void UpdateWithNewData(std::string up) {
        this->data = up;
        Invalidate();
    }


    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MFC_Tutorial_Window, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()       
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// App class
class MyApp :public CWinApp
{
    MFC_Tutorial_Window *wnd;

    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        wnd = new MFC_Tutorial_Window();
        m_pMainWnd = wnd;
        m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(3);

                       wnd->UpdateWithNewData("Hello world!");          
             return 1;
    }
};
```

Does anyone know why OnPaint is spammed by the system? Have been staring at this code for ages and I just can't find it.

Comment: Note that you *almost* always want to use a View class, in which case you do the drawing in OnDraw, and the framework takes care of the details that are causing your current problem(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPaintDC destructor has to be called for the repainting flag to be reset. You need to call `beginPaint();` and `endPaint();` on your `CDC` which should actually be changed to a `CPaintDC`. More importantly, not calling `endPaint();` will cause the context to be repainted no matter what.

Comment: @Pphoenix Nice! Glad I could help :)

Comment: It seems that EndPaint clears the area that I wanted to draw to. Is there a way to make sure that the area that is drawn stays the same until next time I want to redraw, and still keeping EndPaint?

Comment: @Pphoenix [`CPaintDC::m_ps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kdcex8w.aspx) has an `rcPaint` member that holds the update region. You could call [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002.aspx) after calling `EndPaint`. But that sets you back in the same situation of your original question. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Pphoenix I misread your question, I guess you were referring to the **contents**, not the region. To prevent erasing the background you can override [`CWnd::OnEraseBkgnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0a52fkz.aspx) and leave the implementation blank. Whether you return 0 or a nonzero value doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It seems that it was my logic that failed. I cleared the view myself after drawing data instead of before, causing the window to be blank. EndPaint did nothing wrong. Thanks for the answer though, helped me with another problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

A `WM_PAINT` message is generated whenever there are no other messages in the message queue and the window's update region (see [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002.aspx)) is non-empty. When handling a `WM_PAINT` message an application signals that the update region has been repainted by calling [`EndPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162598.aspx). Failing to call `EndPaint` will not mark the update region as handled, so the next time an application asks for a message, `WM_PAINT` is a valid candidate.

In MFC the functionality to call `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` is encapsulated in the [`CPaintDC` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a48eab8d.aspx). The standard MFC message handler for `WM_PAINT` looks like this:

```
void OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);  // calls BeginPaint()
    // Perform rendering operations on dc
    // ...
} // CPaintDC::~CPaintDC() calls EndPaint()
```

More detailed information on using device contexts can be found at [Device Contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azz5wt61.aspx).